# OnePageScroll text instead of bullets for navigation

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, scroll

I'm making use of the onepage-scroll script from here; https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll. It works really well. I found out that the menu is generated within the js script, and they are now bullets. I prefer to have text next to my bullets, but since I'm not so familiar with jquery I have no idea how to do this.

Somewhere on the internet I found that I needed to add this before my

```
     <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".main").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: "section"
  });
  $("#scroll").click(function(){
  $(".main").jumpTo($(this).data("target"));
  });
    });

</script>
```

And add this in the js found on the plugin website;

```
 $.fn.jumpTo = function(newIndex) {
var el = $(this)
index = $(settings.sectionContainer +".active").data("index");
current = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + index + "']");
next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (newIndex+1) + "']");
if(next.length < 1) {
if (settings.loop == true) {
pos = 0;
next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (newIndex) + "']");
} else {
return
}

}else {
pos = (newIndex * 100) * -1;
}

current.removeClass("active")
next.addClass("active");
if(settings.pagination == true) {
$(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + index + "']").removeClass("active");
$(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + next.data("index") + "']").addClass("active");
}

$("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
$("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))

if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (index + 1);
history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
}
el.transformPage(settings, pos, newIndex);
}
```

And so I did. I defined my menu with this code, also given;

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#" data-target="1" id="scroll">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-target="2" id="scroll">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the old bullet menu is still there and nothing has changed. I uploaded a test page here because I could not seem to get everything into a fiddle.
http://kellyvuijst.nl/konijntjes/test4.html

I'm not sure why this isn't working or if I'm going the complete wrong way with this.

Comment: You may want to consider changing to [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). It allows you to define a menu, which could be the text you are looking for, and **optionally** define vertical or horizontal bullets.

Comment: It also has an option `scrollOverflow` which could be great for your second section, as in my screen it is not possible to read the bottom of it. Here's [an example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) Oh, and it would work in old browsers as well. (IE8, Opera 12...)

Comment: Doesn't really work well in the demo even, sometimes I need to scroll for a very long time to get it to move and sometimes it moves instant... Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: what browser are you using? Are you using a mouse or a trackpad. Are you talking about the scrolling inside sections or the normal scroll? It works well for me.

Comment: It does that in both safari and chrome, I'm using a normal mouse. The normal scroll does that. I found that it only does that occasionally though. I tried building up from the documentation and so far that works fine, no weird behaviour yet except for bootstrap being annoying.